# How to disable a TreeView control without selecting all nodes?

Tags: delphi, controls, delphi-2009

I don't know if this is a bug or something, but if I try to disable a `TTreeView` control, all the nodes become selected (grayed out)... Can anything be done to just disable the input for this control without changing the selection ? Of course, the node are not really selected, they are just visually selected, but this is annoying.

[image]

Comment: Enable runtime themes?

Comment: They are enabled (in Delphi project options), but I have Windows 7 with classic theme. :)

Comment: Place the tree view in a panel and disable the panel instead.

Comment: @Peter - There will be no visual indication if the treeview is disabled or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's how the disabled control looks like when no theme is applied. You can modify it with little intervention to item drawing:

```delphi
procedure TForm1.TreeView1AdvancedCustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomTreeView;
  Node: TTreeNode; State: TCustomDrawState; Stage: TCustomDrawStage;
  var PaintImages, DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  if (not TreeView1.Enabled) and
      (GetWindowTheme(TreeView1.Handle) = 0) and (Stage = cdPrePaint) then begin
    TreeView1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWindow; // or TreeView1.Color
    TreeView1.Canvas.Font.Color := clGrayText;
  end;
end;
```

Unfortunately the `State` never includes 'cdsDisabled' or 'cdsGrayed' (which I didn't investigate), so the code tests if the treeview is enabled or not.

Comment: Great ! It's exactly what I needed. But I included in the test `...and not (cdsSelected in State)` so the selected node remains grayed like it should. So, thanks a lot, Sertac Akyuz ! :)