# How to make TTreeView not highlight all nodes when disabled?

Tags: delphi, treeview, vcl-styles

I'm using VCL Styles in my application, specifically using "Windows 10 dark" which is black with white text. Then I have a `TTreeView` control, which shows perfectly fine. However, when the user enters "Edit" mode, I disable the `TTreeView`, and when it's disabled, it looks extremely ugly, showing every node highlighted.

[image]

How do I make it so that it shows normal when disabled, without highlighting all nodes, but just highlighting the current selected node only?

NOTE: I'm trying to avoid custom drawing. While that looks the necessary course of action, I'm really not aiming to make this some super complex solution, so alternatives such as the virtual tree view are not in the picture.

---

**EDIT**

[image]

I've tried to implement the recommended "[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59216513/how-to-disable-a-treeview-control-without-selecting-all-nodes#comment104649930_59216513)", but to no avail. Here's what I added:

```
procedure TfrmTopics.TopicTreeAdvancedCustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomTreeView;
  Node: TTreeNode; State: TCustomDrawState; Stage: TCustomDrawStage;
  var PaintImages, DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  inherited;
  if (not TopicTree.Enabled) and
    (GetWindowTheme(TopicTree.Handle) = 0) and (Stage = cdPrePaint) then
  begin
    DefaultDraw:= True; // False; //Tried both ways...
    TopicTree.Canvas.Brush.Color := TopicTree.Color;
    TopicTree.Canvas.Font.Color := clWhite; 
    TopicTree.Canvas.Pen.Color:= clWhite;
  end;
end;
```

It only draws the currently selected node's text - not the rest. I'm assuming it has to do with the dark style and overriding colors...

Which, by the way, the `TTreeView.StyleElements` has `seFont` and `seClient` disabled.

Comment: Related: [How to disable a TreeView control without selecting all nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59216513/how-to-disable-a-treeview-control-without-selecting-all-nodes#comment104649930_59216513). The accepted answer suggests custom drawing though.

Comment: @PeterWolf Geez, I actually searched Google and Stack Overflow before asking, and didn't come across that one.

Comment: @PeterWolf However with no success. That answer doesn't consider VCL Styles, and although I've tweaked the code to my needs, in the end the entire control shows blank. Will come back to this in some time...

Comment: Yes, that's why this isn't a dupe. In comment under that question I suggested disabling container as quick workaround, however you will lose visual state indication as it was pointed out by Sertac.

Comment: I really hate VCL styles, the idea is nice but the implementation is just so damn flawed and buggy, it is constantly broken, and Embarcadero just can't seem to get it working right. This is why I only use Windows styles and will never use VCL styles

Comment: @RemyLebeau While I agree, our software has become fundamentally rooted in it. Given, this is a side project, not a part of the actual software. Just an internal tool. That's why I'm not looking for anything real fancy. But I at least need it to be presentable.

Comment: @PeterWolf Actually the more I look at it, the more I realize it almost is a dupe. After all, the "select all" behavior seems to be rooted in the control itself, regardless of how it's drawn in the UI. Just, the solution there, although tweaked to my needs, just doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `VCL Styles Utils` components from: https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-utils

Include `Vcl.Styles.Hooks` in your project

Comment: Most excellent, much better looking. Now if only I can figure out how to keep the currently selected node highlighted...